# Jump between all the matchadd matches for a group?

Tags: regular-expression, matchadd

One can use the `matchadd` function to add to groups of matches that will be highlighted in the VIM editor.

But how does one jump between the matches within a specific group?

Comment: You might be able to work with `getmatches`, but since `matchadd` takes a pattern I would either `/pattern` or `:vimgrep /pattern/ %`

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are trying to use syntax highlighting as a way to move in your buffer, Ben's comment is probably right: using the search of a grep command is easier. But if you are trying to do clever stuff with your syntax highlighting maybe [`:h getmatches()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getmatches%28%29) could be useful: it returns the matches you added with `matchadd()` so maybe you can use this command to get the patterns and then use these patterns in a search.

Comment: @statox I'm trying to highlight things in a log file and jump to them, but maybe in different colors...I know you can use different groups to highlight different colors.